# What version of SpringRouteBuilder has log and onException members?

Tags: java, maven

I've gotten a Maven project from someone and tried to build it. At first it did not have a definition for SpringRouteBuilder, so I went to findJar and got apache-camel-1.3.0.jar. The system started seeing the class, but is still complaining about log member and onException method. Which JAR should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on with which version your project was build and tested. If you don't know that you can try with the newest Camel version which is 2.14.0. If this project does not depend on any undocumented behaviour present in some previous versions it should work fine. Otherwise you might try running it with various 2.X.X versions. Don't use Camel 1.X.X as it is really old.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I'm not actively tracking the history of JARs and am prone to strange choices like this one :).Funny thing, though - even though my Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite) underlines that member and that method in red, Maven build seems to have no problem finding them...

Comment: This happens quite often. Just a side note: you might need to include camel-spring jar in addition to camel-core. Hope it will work.